# Function to track all events on a page via Google Tag Manager data layer

Tags: function, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, google-datalayer

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, but I haven't seen anything similar.

I'm looking for a function to dynamically track events on my pages through Google Tag Manager data layer without having to write new code for each and ever new button or link added to the page.

Is there a way to track them via their unique IDs with a single function?

Thank yoU!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to set it up via GTM without the need of adding any new code to your website.

In your GTM dashboard go to **Variables** -> **Built-In Variables** and click on **Configure**

Here in "**Configure Built-In Variables**" make sure that **Click ID** is selected under **Clicks** section.

Now to setup trigger for your events go back to dashboard and select **Triggers** -> **New** -> **Trigger Configuration** -> under **Click** select **All Elements**

On the trigger configuration screen check **Some Clicks** and select **Click ID** from drop down menu. Now you can filter based on your needs, for example with **RegEx**. For example:

[image]

If you have a long list of IDs I recommend some other approach such as custom variable.

I hope this helps.